# What is the common name for this device that is used to lock up keys?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What is the best word to refer to the thing in the image below?
I want a word that is super clear so when I tell someone to take the key inside it, they know what I am talking about.

[image: box to store keys with combination 9476, attached to a fence]

Comment: There isn't a *common* name for this *rare* thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a lock box. For a bit more precision you can call it a door combination lock box.

See for example:

- [Key Lock Box, Combination Lockbox with Code for House Key Storage, Combo Door Locker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07D8RYGVY)
- [Key Safe Lock Box For Your Front Door](https://youtube.com/watch?v=FsTn1MKTKZQ)

---

According to [Collins](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/lockbox), it's known as a *lockbox* in the US and a *keysafe* in the UK.

Comment: Is lock box the term that is used in the U.S? In this Australian store, it's referred as "(Portable) Key Storage Safe" https://www.bunnings.com.au/products/building-hardware/security-safety-products/safes-cashboxes/cash-boxes-key-cases

Comment: Great answer. It's nice to know that it's actually a compound word in UK and US . `lockbox/keysafe`. In Australia `key safe` seems to be the common form of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a **lock box**.

It's often used by real estate agents to store the keys for a house so that any agent with the combination can get the keys. It's sometimes used with AirBnB properties as well.